# displaying user next to its associated message in a feed

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

quick question that should be simple to answer despite trouble i've had:

i have a simple rails app with a message ('intro') tab displaying sent and received messages ('intros'). i have the messages routing from user to user appropriately, and the content of the messages is displaying fine in user inboxes. however, i'm having trouble showing the name's of the users associated with the messages next to the messages themselves

i have a User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :one_liner, :password, :password_confirmation
    has_secure_password

    has_many :sent_intros, foreign_key: "sender_id", dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Intro"
    has_many :received_intros, foreign_key: "receiver_id", dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Intro"

    has_many :receivers, through: :sent_intros, source: :receiver
    has_many :senders, through: :received_intros, source: :sender

        ...
```

, an Intro (message) model:

```
class Intro < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :receiver_id, :sender_id

  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User"

  ...
```

and here is the relevant code from the users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @intro = Intro.find(params[:id])

    @sent_intros = current_user.sent_intros.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @received_intros = current_user.received_intros.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
  ...
```

my .erb show page:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>

                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>
        </section>
    </aside>
    <div class="span8">
        <% if@user.received_intros.any? %>
            <h3>Received intros (<%= @user.received_intros.count %>)</h3>
            <ol class="intros">
                <%= render @received_intros %>
            </ol>
            <%= will_paginate @received_intros %>
        <% end %>

        <% if@user.sent_intros.any? %>
            <h3>Sent intros (<%= @user.sent_intros.count %>)</h3>
            <ol class="intros">
                <%= render @sent_intros %>
            </ol>
            <%= will_paginate @sent_intros %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

so I'm concerned with the <%= render @received_intros %> and <%= render @sent_intros %> lines of this page

currently, it displays the following (intro content without the associated user):

[image]

how do I get prefix those usernames to their respective intros? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking up Intro based on the same id as User in your controller actions. Since it's looked up second, it's overwriting the @user variable.  Here's your code:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@intro = Intro.find(params[:id])
```

I'm guessing you probably want that second line to be something like params[:intro_id], but not entirely sure without seeing the view code linking to that page and possibly your routes file.

Comment: didn't do the trick. keep in mind the User model includes has_many/through line items. am i missing an @x = User.find(params[:y][:z]) ?

Comment: No, the problem I'm pointing out is that you're looking up both a User and an Intro given the same id. Also, it's not clear what "@intro" is in your controller. If you take out the "@intro = ..." line, does that help?

Comment: ok, thanks! and no, simply taking out the @intro line doesn't help. i think i'd definitely need to add code to the Users controller (show field) that pulls out the sender and receiver associated with each intro. something that would go before the 'current_user.sent_intros.paginate(page: params[:page])' in the  '@sent_intros' line?